# Why does a linux guest consume 100% of the host CPU under VirtualBox when the guest appears idle?

Tags: virtualbox, cpu

I am using VirtualBox on a Macbook Pro running Yosemite.

My linux guests sometimes consume 100% of the host CPU (viewed in Activity Monitor) even though the guest is idle.

Why is the host CPU utilization so high and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

From the VirtualBox [manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch12.html):

**12.4.1. Linux guests may cause a high CPU load**

> Some Linux guests may cause a high CPU load even if the guest system
>   appears to be idle. This can be caused by a high timer frequency of
>   the guest kernel. Some Linux distributions, for example Fedora, ship a
>   Linux kernel configured for a timer frequency of 1000Hz. We recommend
>   to recompile the guest kernel and to select a timer frequency of
>   100Hz.
>
> Linux kernels shipped with Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) as of
>   release 4.7 and 5.1 as well as kernels of related Linux distributions
>   (for instance CentOS and Oracle Linux) support a kernel parameter
>   divider=N. Hence, such kernels support a lower timer frequency without
>   recompilation. We suggest to add the kernel parameter divider=10 to
>   select a guest kernel timer frequency of 100Hz.

Comment: Running `cpufreq-set -g powersave` on the guest machine may help keep CPU frequencies down when the guest machine is idle.

Comment: @amphetamachine, no, since the guest can't change the frequency of the real cpu.

Comment: Although this is the only suggestion I found for my issue, it hasn't resolved the problem.  I have confirmed that my kernel (3.16.0-4) is using CONFIG_HZ=250.